# Multiple bindings in IIS slowing down all other sites

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7.5

On a Windows 2008 Server in IIS 7.5 we have about 60 websites.

A majority of those sites only have a couple of bindings...

- example1.com
- www.example1.com

But we have one website that has nearer 160 bindings for various domains.

In the past couple days all our sites have started to run slower; however when we turn off the site with the silly amount of bindings everything runs as normal.

How would that number of bindings affect the speed of the overall server? Is there a way we can limit the server resources that site may be using?

Comment: What is becoming slower?  The throughput or the response time?  How much memory is being used by the application pool(s) and inetinfo.exe?  What is the CPU load when this occurs?

Comment: The response time of all sites slows down as soon as the site in question is running. Once disabled in IIS and the application pool everything speeds up again. CPU load hardly changes, never goes above 12%. Memory usage is hardly anything.